# Why Yii2 uses abbreviated methods names in yii\caching\Cache?

Tags: yii, yii2, naming-conventions

Methods of `yii\caching\Cache`:

- [`madd()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html#madd()-detail),
- [`mget()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html#mget()-detail) and
- [`mset()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html#mset()-detail),

are **the only** (known to me) **in entire Yii2 core**, that are using abbreviated names. Following naming convetions used *everywhere else*, they should be named `multiAdd`, `multiGet` and `multiSet`.

Does anyone know, why exception has been made for this one (?) class?

*I'm reviewing a book about Yii2 right now, and I was so extremely surprised to findout these names, that at first I'd bet a lot, that book author made a mistake! Abreviated methods names in Yii2?*

Comment: I think you should post an issue on yii2's github. You will probably get a better response there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it was done in haste and is inherited from Yii1. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#mget-detail

No one thought about it then. And now it is BC

**UPD:** Added in [Ideas for 2.1](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/wiki/Ideas-for-2.1#cache)

**UPD2** https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/10296

Comment: Thanks for a quick reaction. That was actually a wonder or question, not an issue or to-do request. Consider adding [8931](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8931) to 2.1 wish-list, as this is really something, that bothers me.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I guess it was named so for short. For now we can create `multiSet`, `multiGet`, `multiAdd` methods, and make the existing `mset`, `mget` and `madd` method as aliases for them. Then mark old methods as `DEPRECATED` until Yii 2.1, then just drop them.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reaction. That was actually a wonder or question, not an issue or to-do request. Consider adding [8931](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8931) to 2.1 wish-list, as this is really something, that bothers me.